# Using multiple .style.transform on same element

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-transforms

It seems that by using two cases of `obj.style.transform` in succession results in only the first statement being executed. Please see the below code. A full example is on [CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/OMXYoG).

```
function animateObject(x, y, z){
    object = document.getElementsByClassName('cub-1')[0];

    object.style.transform = "rotateX(" + x + "deg)";
    object.style.transform = "rotateY(" + y + "deg)";
    alert("")
}
```

In the full example, I am reading lines from a text area which contains x, y and z positions of an object, converting the values from radians to degrees and then animating my 3d object using these values.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When applying multiple transforms to the same element, they should be added as space separated values to the same property like below. Otherwise, they would get overwritten (only the `rotateY` will be applied because it is the latest).

```
object.style.transform = "rotateX(" + x + "deg)";
object.style.transform += "rotateY(" + y + "deg)";
```

I have added an `alert` of the `object.style.transform` to both the original snippet and the modified version and we can see how the original one always outputs only the `rotateY` whereas the changed one outputs both `rotateX()` and `rotateY()` together.

[**Original Code with Alerts added**](http://codepen.io/hari_shanx/pen/zrBVBp) | 
[**Modified Code with Alerts added**](http://codepen.io/hari_shanx/pen/JGKqzM)

Comment: @MikeResoli: Glad that I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`DOMMatrix`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMMatrix) to build/chain your CSS `transform`.

Then *stringify* the resultant matrice with its build in `DOMMatrixReadOnly.toString()`. Which returns CSS ready `transform` syntax.

```js
window.onload = () => {
  const getStyle = id => document.getElementById(id).style;

  // Rotate in plane
  getStyle('Ⅰ').transform = new DOMMatrix('rotateZ(45deg)');
  // Rotate from [1,1] vector (diagonal)                      (same as Ⅰ)
  getStyle('Ⅱ').transform = new DOMMatrix().rotateFromVectorSelf(1, 1);
  // Rotate matrix on Z axis.                                  (same as Ⅰ & Ⅱ)
  getStyle('Ⅲ').transform = new DOMMatrix().rotateAxisAngleSelf(0, 0, 1, 45);

  // Rotate matrix on X axis. Then rotate matrix on Y axis.
  getStyle('Ⅳ').transform = new DOMMatrix('rotateX(45deg) rotateY(45deg)');
  // Rotate matrix on X axis. Then rotate matrix on Y axis    (same as Ⅳ)
  getStyle('Ⅴ').transform = new DOMMatrix('rotateX(45deg)').multiply(new DOMMatrix('rotateY(45deg)'));

  // Rotate matrix on Y axis. Then rotate matrix on X axis.
  getStyle('Ⅵ').transform = new DOMMatrix('rotateY(45deg)').multiply(new DOMMatrix('rotateX(45deg)'));
  // Rotate matrix on Y/X axis.                               (same as Ⅵ)
  getStyle('Ⅶ').transform = new DOMMatrix().rotateSelf(45, 45);
};
```

```css
.element {
  transition: transform 1s;
  padding: 5px;
  opacity: .7;
}

.element::after {
  content: attr(id);
}

#Ⅰ { background: red; transition-delay: 0s;}
#Ⅱ { background: green; transition-delay: 1s; }
#Ⅲ { background: blue; transition-delay: 2s; }
#Ⅳ { background: orange; transition-delay: 3s; }
#Ⅴ { background: purple; transition-delay: 4s; }
#Ⅵ { background: pink; transition-delay: 5s; }
#Ⅶ { background: coral; transition-delay: 6s;}

.frame {
  position: relative;
  margin: 20px;
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  grid-auto-columns: 80px;
  grid-auto-rows: 80px;
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="frame">
  <div class="element" id="Ⅰ"></div>
  <div class="element" id="Ⅱ"></div>
  <div class="element" id="Ⅲ"></div>
  <div class="element" id="Ⅳ"></div>
  <div class="element" id="Ⅴ"></div>
  <div class="element" id="Ⅵ"></div>
  <div class="element" id="Ⅶ"></div>
</div>
```